# Find all complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

$\forall{n}\in\mathbb{N}$ find all complex numbers $z$ satisfying the equation $z^n=-\bar{z}$.
I found $0$ and $1$ and for other? How can I prove it?

Comment: Polar form${}$?

Comment: Are you asked to find the solutions that work simultaneously for all $n$, or are you asked to find, for each $n$, the solutions that work for that particular $n$?

Comment: I asked to find the solutions that work simultaneously for all n

Comment: With polar form I have $r^n[cos(n\theta)+isin(n\theta)]=r[-cos(\theta)+isin(\theta)]$

Comment: @Sandrin And what does that tell you about $r$? Once that's nailed down, what does it tell you about $\theta?

Comment: @Arthur $r$ can be $0$ or $1$ for $\theta$ i can't compare it because in the second member cosine is negative

Comment: If $r=0$, then we don't care about $\theta$. If $r=1$, consider the two special cases $n=1$ and $n=2$, and for each of those, what $\cos(n\theta)=-\cos(\theta)$ says. You can narrow it down quite a lot from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\displaystyle z^n = -\overline z$.

Let $\displaystyle z = re^{i\theta}$, giving $\displaystyle r^ne^{in\theta} = -re^{-i\theta}$

Since the modulus of the two sides has to be equal, $\displaystyle r^n = r$, giving the solutions $\displaystyle r=0$ and $\displaystyle r=1$. $\displaystyle r=0 \implies z=0$ is a single solution, while $\displaystyle r = 1 \implies z = e^{i\theta}$ is a set of solutions we need to find.

We have $\displaystyle e^{in\theta} = -e^{-i\theta}$

$\displaystyle e^{i\theta(n+1)} = -1$

$\displaystyle e^{i\theta(n+1)} = e^{(2k+1)i\pi}, \forall k \in \mathbb{Z}$

Hence $\displaystyle \theta = \frac{2k+1}{n+1}\pi, \forall k \in \mathbb{Z}$

giving $\displaystyle z = e^{i(\frac{2k+1}{n+1})\pi} = \cos (\frac{2k+1}{n+1})\pi + i\sin (\frac{2k+1}{n+1})\pi , \forall k \in \mathbb{Z}$

To eliminate duplicate solutions, consider the argument modulo $\displaystyle 2\pi$.

Answer (score 4):

If $z^n=-\overline z$, then $z^{n+1}=-\overline zz=-|z|^2$. So, $|z|^{n+1}=|z|^2$ and therefore $|z|=0(\iff z=0)$ or $|z|=1$, unless $n=1$ (but the equation $z=-\overline z$ is easy to solve: its solutions are the purely imaginary numbers). So, unless $z=0$, you know that $z=e^{i\theta}$ for some $\theta\in\Bbb R$. And then your equation becomes $e^{in\theta}=e^{-i\theta}$. Can you take it from here?